# dnx-watch stopped working and throwing ArgumentException because directory was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

I have an ASP.NET Core (RC1 Final) solution with multiple projects. I have a web project in c:\projects\MySolution\src\Web and multiple class lib projects in c:\projects\MySolution\src. The class libs are added as project references in the Web app.

I've been running the web app `using dnx-watch web` for a long time without problems, but now it's crashing with the following exception:

```
C:\projects\MySolution\src\Web
> dnx-watch web
[DnxWatcher] info: Running dnx with the following arguments: --project C:\projects\MySolution\src\Web\project.json web
[DnxWatcher] info: dnx process id: 40668
System.ArgumentException: The directory name C:\projects\MySolution\src\MultiTenancy\project.json is invalid.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor(String path, String filter)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor(String path)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher.Core.FileWatcher.AddWatcher(String path)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher.Core.FileWatcher.WatchProject(String projectPath)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher.Core.DnxWatcher.AddProjectAndDependeciesToWatcher(IProject project, IFileWatcher fileWatcher)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher.Core.DnxWatcher.AddProjectAndDependeciesToWatcher(IProject project, IFileWatcher fileWatcher)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher.Core.DnxWatcher.<WaitForProjectFileToChangeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

It looks like dnx-watch is trying to interpret project.json as a directory. I'm not sure why this behavior has suddenly changed. I suspect it happened after a added another project reference to the web project, but I'm not able to get it back to working condition.

I know (hope) RC2 and dotnet cli is right around the corner, but it would be nice to get this working before I can do the switch..

Comment: Sorry to hear that you're hitting that exception. Can you please share the exact project structure (folder names) and the project reference graph? There is definitely a bug there, but since we're done with `dnx-watch` and switched to `dotnet-watch` I will not back port a fix for rc1 (sorry). However, I want to make sure that `dotnet-watch` doesn't have the same problem. You can log a bug at https://github.com/aspnet/dotnet-watch/issues/new

Comment: I just posted an issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/dotnet-watch/issues/79